# Parse XML file in groovy with "-" in node name

Tags: xml, groovy

if i parse this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rootnode>
  <testnode info="Test1"/>
  <testnode info="Test2"/>
</rootnode>
```

with this pice of groovy code all works fine:

```
def parser = new XmlParser()
def result = parser.parse(new File('test.xml').getCanonicalPath())
result.testnode.each {node -> println node.'@info'}
```

But if the node name change from "testnode" to "test-node"

i got the following message:

`Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: node for class:..`

How can i solve this problem (the content of the xml is untouchable)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to quote the nodename so Groovy knows it's not a subtraction:

```
result.'test-node'.each {node -> println node.'@info'}
```